# Form randomly switching to different record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I put together a small database application for a client. They wanted it in Access, as their staff is comfortable with it; no problem, they've got SQL Server to use for a back-end. Roughly speaking, it's used to track and research property inheritance.

Most of the action happens on the "Person" form, which is bound to a query that joins the Person table to a couple simple lookup tables (all linked tables to SQL Server). There is a subform for assigning staff members that will research the person, and a tab control that has a couple more subforms (person details, relatives, linked legal documents, etc.) There's a little bit of VBA here and there, but it's nothing too fancy.

Here's the problem we're seeing, and so far the client hasn't been able to pin down a repro (I've never been able to make it happen on my development system): Sometimes, after the user has entered details on the Person form, they will focus one of the subforms to assign them to a staff member, or set relatives, and the Person form will suddenly switch to a different record in the database.

I've tried disabling the event procedure for Form_Activate on the Person form, which was just enabling/disabling a button based on whether another form was open to an existing record. I've confirmed that it's very unlikely that the users are accidentally hitting Page Up/Page Down and navigating to a different record. This was also happening occasionally in testing with a single user, so I suspect it's not a concurrency issue.

Anybody ever seen anything remotely like this before? I've never experienced Access randomly switching to different records, and I've made several Access apps using SQL Server as a back-end.

Comment: If they are navigating the form entry by pressing the 'Tab' key it might be cycling to a new record that way?  I would try setting the forms 'Cycle' Property to 'Current Record', default is 'All Records' and jumps to a new record if you press 'Tab' having the last control in the tab order focused, which is often times a sub form.

Comment: Thanks Fink, thought of that one already, and forgot to mention it. I've made sure that all forms of interest are set to "Current Record", and have done some mashing of the Tab key to make sure that's not what's causing it. I'm baffled that they apparently have multiple users with this issue, yet I've not been able to reproduce it so far.

Comment: If your confident that no form events are causing this behavior, could it be caused by any foreign key rules or triggers on the clients SQL server? Maybe these differ between the clients server and your server?   Possibly it's something with SQL permissions, or network related?  I'm starting to run out of ideas

Comment: @Fink Don't feel bad, I ran out of ideas long ago on this one. :) Good idea with the schema comparison. Maybe I'll double check that later today. I'm definitely using a few triggers, and plenty of foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured out what was going on. I sat down with the front-end and started pounding data into it until I finally hit the wonky behavior. Profiler was running the whole time. As soon as I got an unexpected record switch, I looked over in Profiler's output, and saw a really obvious smoking gun:

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

Access is using the `@@IDENTITY` variable to get the ID of the freshly-inserted record. Problem: I have a trigger on this table, which also inserts a record into *another* table if a field happens to have a certain value. Naturally, this second table has an identity column. This is clobbering `@@IDENTITY`, and when Access attempts to requery the record it just inserted, it ends up with a different one entirely (by virtue of the ID it *does* get almost certainly having a match in the Person table).

I know the ideal situation would be to eliminate this trigger and move this automatic insert into VBA code, but I need to "make it work now" with minimal changes, so here's the really horrid hack I'm going with for now.

In your trigger that inserts additional records, do this on the very first line:

```
DECLARE @id int = @@IDENTITY
```

Then at the very end of the trigger, do this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'DECLARE @hack TABLE (id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(' + CAST(@id AS varchar) + ', 1), a char(1)); INSERT INTO @hack (a) VALUES (''a'');'
EXEC (@sql)
```

That will save the value of `@@IDENTITY` in a local variable, then (via dynamic SQL) declare a table variable with an ID column beginning at the previous value of `@@IDENTITY`. It inserts a dummy row, which then resets the value of that variable to whatever it was prior to the trigger inserting rows elsewhere.

It's an awful, awful hack, but it'll do for now.